# look for a smaller value and copy it to the other column using onchange jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have table like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>limit</td>
        <td>price</td>
        <td>aproved price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="limit_1" type="text" name="limit" value="200.000"></td>
        <td><input id="price_1" type="text" onChange="getapprice()" name="price" value="300.000"></td>
        <td><input id="appprice_1" type="text" name="appprice" value="200.000"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="limit_2" type="text" name="limit" value="250.000"></td>
        <td><input id="price_2" type="text" onChange="getapprice()" name="price" value="150.000"></td>
        <td><input id="appprice_2" type="text" name="appprice" value="150.000"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

when i insert the value in column price and the getapprice function is give result where prices are lower than the column rows and columns price, then the results of the smaller will be displayed in the column price approval.

I've been looking for but did not find the same question and answer.

Comment: You are missing closing tr tags.

Comment: could you post `getapprice()` and what problem you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code.

```js
function getapprice(e)
{
  var target = e.target;
  var price = parseFloat($(target).val());
  var row = $(target).closest("tr");
  var limit = parseFloat(row.find("[name='limit']").val());
  var app_price = price < limit ? price : limit;
  row.find("[name='appprice']").val(app_price);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>limit</td><td>price</td><td>aproved price</td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="limit_1" type="text" name="limit" value="200.000"></td>
<td><input id="price_1" type="text" onChange="getapprice(event)" name="price" value="300.000"></td>
<td><input id="appprice_1" type="text" name="appprice" value="200.000"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="limit_2" type="text" name="limit" value="250.000"></td>
<td><input id="price_2" type="text" onChange="getapprice(event)" name="price" value="150.000"></td>
<td><input id="appprice_2" type="text" name="appprice" value="150.000"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.